# URL Rewrite works on local MAMP but not on hosting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My (dot) htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^movie/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ movie.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^movie/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ movie.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^actor/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ actor.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^actor/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ actor.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^topfilms/$ topfilms.php
RewriteRule ^topfilms$ topfilms.php

RewriteRule ^topactors/$ topactors.php
RewriteRule ^topactors$ topactors.php
```

The above works perfectly fine on my MAMP based localhost server. But, when i uploaded the script to my web hosting, it does not work and I get a 500 Internal Server error.

There are no problems with file permissions, and it appears to be a problem with the above htaccess only.

But, I can not understand what it is!

Comment: Does your hosting have mod_rewrite enabled and allows to overwrite configuration via `.htaccess`. From your description and error, I'd guess not.

Comment: Remove the .htaccess and make sure your PHP code is working, that's the first step. Second step look for the error_log file and see if there is any errors related.

Comment: @nmaier Yes, mod_rewrite is enabled for sure.

Comment: @Prix the code works perfectly fine, because when i access the URLs in a standard fashion using /movie.php?id=10, everything shows up correctly.

Comment: @RohitSmith check the error_log in some hosts they dump rewrite error there if any.

Comment: Yes, I checked the error logs from cPanel. From that only thing I was able to make out was that htaccess is causing the error. Nothing else.

Comment: And what is the complete error message it tells you on the error_log there?

Comment: Also can you remove all your rules and try with this one just to see if anything changes? `RewriteRule ^(movie|actor)/([\w-/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]`